# Connecting OAuth2 resource server with authentication server

Tags: rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to make a sample OAuth2 Spring authorization and resource server. My intention is to implement two separate applications - one representing authorization server ant the other representing resource server. Since I'm quite a beginner in Spring Security, I guess I need some guidance to complete my task.

I already managed to implement a simple authorization server using in-memory token store (app named "OAuth").

AuthServerOAuth2Config.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerOAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "myResource";

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler handler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
         // @formatter:off
         clients.inMemory()
                 .withClient("test")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("test")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(300).//invalid after 5 minutes.
                    refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//refresh after 10 minutes.
         // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).userApprovalHandler(handler).authenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

}
```

OAuth2SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuth2SecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("javabycode").password("123456").roles("USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("admin").password("admin123").roles("ADMIN");
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
         http
         .csrf().disable()
         .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

}
```

Accessing `http://localhost:9081/OAuth/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin123` returns token as expected, so I'm guessing that authorization server is configured ok.

Now there's a resource server part (app named "RestTest"). I've managed to find some examples using `RemoteTokenServices` to access token service that resides in another app. So here's my resource server so far.

OAuth2ResourceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "myResource";

    private TokenExtractor tokenExtractor = new BearerTokenExtractor();

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.
        anonymous().disable()
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/v1/**")
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/v1/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws 
        Exception {
         resources.tokenServices(tokenService()).resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(true);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:9081/OAuth/oauth/check_token/");
        tokenService.setClientId("test");
        tokenService.setClientSecret("test");
        return tokenService;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to secure my REST API (`http://localhost:9081/RestTest/v1/foobar`) so I believe that configuration above is correct, right?  Problem is that when I access `v1/foobar` endpoint (via Postman) it's accessible without any authentication. So I think I'm simply missing some part of configuration, but I can't figure it out how to connect to authorization server correctly. One more thing to mention - I'm not using Spring Boot!

I'd really appreciate some guidance to make my sample work. Thanks!

EDIT1: I've added `resourceId` to both authentication and resource server - no luck. Is `resourceId` even mandatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `RESOURCE_ID` both in `ResourceServer` and `AuthorizationServer` in a way that, (you updated your question though with that snippet)

```
@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.tokenServices(tokenService()).resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(true);
}
```

And in your auth server

```
.scopes("read", "write", "trust").resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
```

Add a `springSecurityFilterChain` as you missing that in `web.xml` that you already said in comment

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

From [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#hello-web-security-java-configuration):

> It creates a Servlet Filter known as the **springSecurityFilterChain** which is responsible for all the security (protecting the application URLs, validating submitted username and passwords, redirecting to the log in form, etc) within your application.

Comment: how can i configure same in Spring Boot

Comment: Which part you want to configure? Filter ?

Comment: Filter .. i am implementing spring oauth2.0 and created authserver but facing some difficulties to configure resourceserver.  resourceserver and authserver are on different port.

Comment: @PiyushMittal, You can ask another question describing your problem.